# How to handle the Unexpected arg eval type (org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.MissingArgEval) in apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to parse an excel file which contains various kind of fomulas.The code i have writen is able to parse almost all kind of formulas but , some of the cells contains reference of another cell like =C20 like this. In this type of cells my code is having

```
 Unexpected arg eval type (org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.MissingArgEval)
```

My code is able to handle below types

```
 =IF(D14=0;" - ";E14/D14), =IF('TreeData-Report'!AB92="H";"";SUM('TreeData-Report'!C92:'TreeData-Report'!E92)) .. etc.
```

But when it is coming as  a single argument like C20,D14 ..etc, it is failing .
And i will post the code where exactly it is failing

```
      while (cellIterator.hasNext() && cellIteratorTotal.hasNext()) {

            cellCount++;
            Cell currentCell = cellIterator.next();

            Cell currentCellTotal = cellIteratorTotal.next();


            String cellValue = excelManager.evalCell(currentCell);// from here i am sending the  value for validation 
            String cellValueTotal = excelManager.evalCell(currentCellTotal);
```

This is the validator class where i am chekcing thetype of the cell value

```
public String evalCell(Cell cell) {
    String cellValue = "";
    if (cell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.STRING) {
        cellValue = cell.getStringCellValue();
    } else if (cell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.NUMERIC) {
        cellValue = formatDoubleNumberToString(cell.getNumericCellValue());
    } else if (cell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.FORMULA) {
        cellValue = evalFormulaCell(cell);
    }
    return cellValue.trim();
}

public String evalFormulaCell(Cell cell) {

    String cellValue = "";
    switch (formulaEvaluator.evaluateFormulaCellEnum(cell)) {//Here the code fails if cell contains C20,D14.. etc this type of values 
    case BOOLEAN:
        cellValue = String.valueOf(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
        break;
    case NUMERIC:
        cellValue = formatDoubleNumberToString(cell.getNumericCellValue());
        break;
    case STRING:
        cellValue = cell.getStringCellValue();
        break;
    case BLANK:
        cellValue = "";
        break;
    case ERROR:
        cellValue = "Error Occurred with Code :"+String.valueOf(cell.getErrorCellValue());
        break;
    case _NONE:
        cellValue = "";
        break;
    // CELL_TYPE_FORMULA will never occur
    case FORMULA:
        cellValue = "";
        break;
    }
    return cellValue;
}
```

Please help me to handle this kind of errors , and i am very sorry i am am not able to make my post crystal clear.Thanks in advance.I am using poi 3.16 jar.

Comment: I think that simple cell references like `=D12` are not treated as actual formula within `formulaEvaluator.evaluateFormulaCellEnum(cell)`

Comment: But then how i will handle this , all possible combinations are there in the code ?

Comment: Try to use `formulaEvaluator.evaluateFormulaCell()` as  `evaluateFormulaCellEnum` is deprecated

Comment: @XtremeBaumer already tried but the same result

Comment: Maybe your cell content is `D12` and not `=D12`. From the docs `Represents the (intermediate) evaluated result of a missing function argument. In most cases this can be translated into BlankEval but there are some notable exceptions. Functions COUNT and COUNTA do count their missing args. Note - the differences between MissingArgEval and BlankEval have not been investigated fully, so the POI evaluator may need to be updated to account for these as they are found.` sounds like there is a missing function argument

Comment: @XtremeBaumer then  will this problem remain unsolved ?

Comment: Unless you can provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for your problem its hard for us to recreate the problem. I made a very simple program with 2 cells in a workbook and I had no problem evaluating the forumla `=A1`

Comment: you example  working with formulaEvaluator.evaluateFormulaCellEnum(cell)) ?

Comment: Yes, have a look [here](https://ideone.com/P4Awrx) for the example code

Comment: @XtremeBaumer very sorry but can not upload the excel file as it does not belongs to me

Comment: @XtremeBaumer is there no way you can give solution , other than uploading the original file ? If yes please reply back

Comment: If we can't replicate your problem, then we can't help you. If you can create some other file which causes the same problem, then do that

Comment: @XtremeBaumer i will try to do that, but now the now problem is also for simple SUM() also